# Processing JSON to RDD hashMaps

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

This is actually a follow up to a question I asked here [Convert JSON objects to RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383380/convert-json-objects-to-rdd)

The solution I implemented from the answers given is

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature

case class myRec(
            client_title: String,
            made_on_behalf: String,
            country: String,
            email_address: String,
            special_request_made: String,
            number_of_rooms: String,
            is_phone_booking: String,
            cancelled: String)

def prepJson (infile:String) :RDD[myRec] = {
  val input = sc.wholeTextFiles(infile).map(_._2)
  input.mapPartitions(records => {
     val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
     mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
     mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
     records.flatMap(record => {
        try {
         mapper.readValue(record, classOf[List[myRec]])
        } catch {
        case e: Exception => None
        }
     })
  })
}
```

After successfully reading the json file into a case class, It resulted in a `HashMap`

Sample of the generated `HashMap`

```
 Map(client_title -> Mr., made_on_behalf -> 0, country -> Brussel, email_address -> 15e29034@gmail.com, cancelled -> 0, is_phone_booking -> 1, special_request -> 0, ...)
 Map(client_title -> Mr., made_on_behalf -> 0, country -> Bundesliga, email_address -> aae665d95c5d630@aol.com, cancelled -> 1, is_phone_booking -> 1, special_request -> 1, ...)
 Map(client_title -> Mr., made_on_behalf -> 0, country -> Japan, email_address -> fef412c714ff@yahoo.com, cancelled -> 0, is_phone_booking -> 0, special_request -> 0, ...)
```

I want to extract some features, from the resulting case class `RDD` in to a Tuple so I tried this:

```
def process_data (data_json: String) :RDD[(Double, Array[Double])]= {
// Read data
val my_Data = prepJson(data_json)
my_Data.map{ rec =>
    val values = Array(
      rec.made_on_behalf.toDouble,
      rec.special_request_made.toDouble,
      rec.number_of_rooms.toDouble,
      rec.amount.toDouble,
      rec.is_phone_booking.toDouble
    )
    new Tuple2(rec.cancelled.toDouble, values)
  }
}
```

when I call the function

```
val sample_data = process_data("file:///path/to/dataset.json")
sample_data.saveAsTextFile("file:///path/to/data.txt")
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap cannot be cast to myRec
```

Question is how can I go through the hash maps so that `process_data` function will return an Array of `Tuples`?

Thanks!

Comment: There exist unclarties: What is the definition of `myRec`? What and why do you use an ObjectMapper, so what is your exakt purpose?
Please provide `import` statements and indent code properly.

Comment: @MartinSenne Thanks for the correction, incase you missed it, I want to read data from a json file that contains a lot of `json` objects, and hence the use of `ObjectMapper`. This is a follow up on the question I asked here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383380/convert-json-objects-to-rdd/32389461#32389461), and finally I want the `process_data` function to return an array of Tuples.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

The `prepJson` method is not working as expected. Instead of having a `Rdd[MyRec]` you have a `Rdd[Map[_,_]]` at runtime as the conversion to the case class MyRec is not working properly.

## Long answer

I setup a complete scenario

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature


case class MyRec(
                  client_title: String,
                  made_on_behalf: String,
                  country: String,
                  email_address: String,
                  special_request_made: String,
                  number_of_rooms: String,
                  is_phone_booking: String,
                  cancelled: String)

object D {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val c = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Spark eCommerce ETL.")
      .setMaster("local[*]")

    val sc = new SparkContext(c)

    // this is what you actually have
    // ==================================================

//    val mapRdd: RDD[Map[_, _]] = prepJson("./data/dataset.json", sc)
//    // debug
//    val result = mapRdd.collect()
//    println("Result of prepJson is : " + result.mkString(", ") )
    // debug end

    // But this is what you want
    // ==================================================

    val myRecRdd: RDD[MyRec] = prepJsonDoesNotWork("./data/dataset.json", sc)

    val a = myRecRdd.collect()
    println( "MyRecs read from prepJson: " + a.mkString(", "))


    val x = process_data( myRecRdd, sc)
    x.saveAsTextFile("./data/output.json")

    sc.stop
  }

  def process_data( myRecRdd : RDD[MyRec], sc: SparkContext): RDD[(Double, Array[Double])] = {

    myRecRdd.map { rec =>
      val values = Array(
        rec.made_on_behalf.toDouble,
        rec.special_request_made.toDouble,
        rec.number_of_rooms.toDouble,
        // rec.amount.toDouble,
        rec.is_phone_booking.toDouble
      )
      new Tuple2(rec.cancelled.toDouble, values)
    }
  }

  def prepJsonDoesNotWork(inputFile: String, sc: SparkContext) : RDD[MyRec] = {
    val input = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFile).map(_._2)

    // Parse it into a specific case class. We use mapPartitions beacuse:
    // (a) ObjectMapper is not serializable so we either create a singleton object encapsulating ObjectMapper
    //     on the driver and have to send data back to the driver to go through the singleton object.
    //     Alternatively we can let each node create its own ObjectMapper but that's expensive in a map
    // (b) To solve for creating an ObjectMapper on each node without being too expensive we create one per
    //     partition with mapPartitions. Solves serialization and object creation performance hit.
    val result = input.mapPartitions((records: Iterator[String]) => {

      // mapper object created on each executor node
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      // We use flatMap to handle errors
      // by returning an empty list (None) if we encounter an issue and a
      // list with one element if everything is ok (List(_)).
      records.flatMap(record => {
        println("RECORD: " + record)
        try {
          val x: List[MyRec] = mapper.readValue(record, classOf[List[MyRec]])

          println("MyRecs:" + x)
          println("x size: " + x.size)
          println("x0: " + x(0))
          println("x1: " + x(1))
          x.foreach((t: MyRec) => println("  My rec in prepJson  " + t))

          x
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => None
        }
      })
    })

    result
  }
}
```

and json input

```
[
  {"time": "2015-05-01 02:25:47",
   "client_title": "Mr.",
   "made_on_behalf": 0,
   "country": "Brussel",
   "email_address": "15e29034@gmail.com"},
  {"time": "2015-05-01 04:15:03",
    "client_title": "Mr.",
    "made_on_behalf": 0,
    "country": "Bundesliga",
    "email_address": "aae665d95c5d630@aol.com"},
  {"time": "2015-05-01 06:29:18",
    "client_title": "Mr.",
    "made_on_behalf": 0,
    "country": "Japan",
    "email_address": "fef412c714ff@yahoo.com"}
]
```

the (essential) output becomes

```
RECORD: [
{"time": "2015-05-01 02:25:47",
"client_title": "Mr.",
"made_on_behalf": 0,
"country": "Brussel",
"email_address": "15e29034@gmail.com"},
{"time": "2015-05-01 04:15:03",
"client_title": "Mr.",
"made_on_behalf": 0,
"country": "Bundesliga",
"email_address": "aae665d95c5d630@aol.com"},
{"time": "2015-05-01 06:29:18",
"client_title": "Mr.",
"made_on_behalf": 0,
"country": "Japan",
"email_address": "fef412c714ff@yahoo.com"}
]
MyRecs:List(Map(email_address -> 15e29034@gmail.com, country -> Brussel, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 02:25:47, made_on_behalf -> 0), Map(email_address -> aae665d95c5d630@aol.com, country -> Bundesliga, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 04:15:03, made_on_behalf -> 0), Map(email_address -> fef412c714ff@yahoo.com, country -> Japan, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 06:29:18, made_on_behalf -> 0))
x size: 3
x0: Map(email_address -> 15e29034@gmail.com, country -> Brussel, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 02:25:47, made_on_behalf -> 0)
x1: Map(email_address -> aae665d95c5d630@aol.com, country -> Bundesliga, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 04:15:03, made_on_behalf -> 0)
MyRecs read from prepJson:
```

As you can see, x0 (here first read MyRec entry) is

- **Map**(email_address -> 15e29034@gmail.com ......., ... ) **instead of** the wanted
- **MyRec**( 15e29034@gmail.com, Brussel, etc. )

Thus, the conversion into an instance of the case class does not work. For that reason, the conversion in your `process_data' either fails (cast exception) or the returned`Rdd` is empty (as in my case, see "MyRecs read from prepJson:   " which is empty.

This means, that the correct typisation of your prepJson is

```
  def prepJson(inputFile: String, sc: SparkContext) : RDD[Map[_,_]] = {
    val input = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFile).map(_._2)

    // Parse it into a specific case class. We use mapPartitions beacuse:
    // (a) ObjectMapper is not serializable so we either create a singleton object encapsulating ObjectMapper
    //     on the driver and have to send data back to the driver to go through the singleton object.
    //     Alternatively we can let each node create its own ObjectMapper but that's expensive in a map
    // (b) To solve for creating an ObjectMapper on each node without being too expensive we create one per
    //     partition with mapPartitions. Solves serialization and object creation performance hit.
    val result = input.mapPartitions((records: Iterator[String]) => {

      // mapper object created on each executor node
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      // We use flatMap to handle errors
      // by returning an empty list (None) if we encounter an issue and a
      // list with one element if everything is ok (List(_)).
      records.flatMap(record => {
        println("RECORD: " + record)
        try {
          val x: List[Map[_,_]] = mapper.readValue(record, classOf[List[Map[_,_]]])

          x
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => None
        }
      })
    })

    result
  }
```

which then correctly returns

```
Result of prepJson is : Map(email_address -> 15e29034@gmail.com, country -> Brussel, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 02:25:47, made_on_behalf -> 0), Map(email_address -> aae665d95c5d630@aol.com, country -> Bundesliga, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 04:15:03, made_on_behalf -> 0), Map(email_address -> fef412c714ff@yahoo.com, country -> Japan, client_title -> Mr., time -> 2015-05-01 06:29:18, made_on_behalf -> 0)
```

## Solution A

Ask @Holden or @zero323 for a working method in [Convert JSON objects to RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383380/convert-json-objects-to-rdd/32389461#32389461) as I'm not an expert with jackson.

## Solution B

Why not use SparkSQL for parsing? This of course required you to have a json file with one MyRec entry per line (instead of a fully compliant JSON), so

```
{"time": "2015-05-01 02:25:47", "client_title": "Mr.", "made_on_behalf": 0, "country": "Brussel", "email_address": "15e29034@gmail.com"} 
{"time": "2015-05-01 04:15:03", "client_title": "Mr.", "made_on_behalf": 0, "country": "Bundesliga", "email_address": "aae665d95c5d630@aol.com"}
```

Just create an `SQLContext` and a `DataFrame` from a json in that format via

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, DataFrame, UserDefinedFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def readJson(inputFile: String, sc: SparkContext) : DataFrame = {
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  sqlContext.read.json(inputFile)
}
```

Once your `DataFrame` is loaded, you can use

- user defined function (udf) to transform column values and to create new columns from given ones,
- do selects, to restrict on certain columns or
- perform the whole palette of sql operations (either programmatically or via SQL queries).